# Rails / Cappuccino App Not Loading on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, routes, cappuccino

I have a rails app with a cappuccino front end that I am trying to deploy onto Heroku.

The app works fine when I run it on localhost using WEBrick, but when I push onto Heroku I get the error message `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/"):`

Here is the contents of the routing file:

```
CappcourceWs::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :transaction_logs

  resources :users
end
```

Is there a route that I have failed to define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like a heroku-specific problem. My first guess is you need to add a `root` route, such as:

```
CappcourceWs::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'users#login'

  resources :transaction_logs
  resources :users
end
```

...or whatever the appropriate action/view is in your case.